# How many unitary representations are there?

Tags: logic, set-theory, representation-theory

Is "the set of all unitary representations of a locally compact group $G$" a set?
If not, what about the set of equivalence classes of unitary representations?

Note that the latter is different from the unitary dual since I do not restrict to irreducible representations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a Hilbert space $H$, there is a proper class of Hilbert spaces that are isomorphic to $H$. This means that the collection of all unitary representations of a locally compact group $G$ is not a set: given any representation $\theta : G \to U(H)$, you have a a representation $\theta' : G \to U(H')$ for any $H'$ isomorphic to $H$.

The equivalence classes aren't a set, either. But you can form a set with one representative from each equivalence class (by restricting your attention to Hilbert spaces with $|G|$ as a basis).

Comment: Thanks, I just had the same idea and changed the question slightly. WOuld you be so kind as to give me a hint wether the picture looks differently if we consider the set of equivalence classes if unitary representations (equiv. classes being w.r.t unitary equivalence)

Comment: I just updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: You can form a set with one representative for *irreducible* representations, and even for *cyclic* representations, but not for *all* representations, even for the trivial group, because we can take direct sums of representations of arbitrarily large cardinality.